# How to connect to VoiceRSS API with my Lazarus/Delphi program?

Tags: delphi, indy, freepascal, lazarus

On the form of my program, there are `TIdHTTP` and `TButton` components:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  HTTP: TIdHTTP;
  AudioFilePath: string;
  AudioFileContent: TMemoryStream;

begin
  AudioFilePath := 'speech.wav'; // Path to the file to which the audio file will be saved

  HTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  AudioFileContent := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    // Send a request to the VoiceRSS API and receive an audio file
    HTTP.Get('http://api.voicerss.org/?key=1234567890QWERTY&hl=en-us&src=Hello, world!',AudioFileContent);

    // Save the audio file to disk
    AudioFileContent.SaveToFile(AudioFilePath);
  finally
    AudioFileContent.Free;
    HTTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

When I just enter this address (but with my API key):

`http://api.voicerss.org/?key=1234567890QWERTY&hl=en-us&src=Hello, world!`

It automatically starts downloading the audio file where the robot says hello world. But, when I run my program, it shows an error:

[image]

Nothing ................

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text you are sending to the server contains an unencoded space character in the URL:

```pascal
HTTP.Get('http://api.voicerss.org/?key=1234567890QWERTY&hl=en-us&src=Hello, world!',AudioFileContent);
                                                                           ^
```

The space character needs to be [percent-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) as `%20` in a URL:

```pascal
HTTP.Get('http://api.voicerss.org/?key=1234567890QWERTY&hl=en-us&src=Hello,%20world!', AudioFileContent);
                                                                           ^^^
```

A web browser would handle this for you, but you have to do it manually in your code.  You can use Indy's `TIdURI` class to help you with this task (it will also encode other characters that need to be encoded), eg:

```pascal
uses
  ..., IdURI;

var
  sText: string;

sText := 'Hello, world!';
HTTP.Get('http://api.voicerss.org/?key=1234567890QWERTY&hl=en-us&src=' + TIdURI.ParamsEncode(sText), AudioFileContent);
```